# Merging multiple JSON objects into a single object AND adding the unequal data into this object as an array

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a Laravel join database query which returns me this:

```
[
  {
    "post_id": 28,
    "site_id": 16,
    "url": "http://something.com",
    "title": "Website title",
    "post_created_at": "2015-07-06 02:40:01",
    "post_updated_at": "2015-09-08 22:33:20",
    "tag_map_id": 11,
    "tag_id": 9,
    "tag_name": "dog"
  },
  {
    "post_id": 28,
    "site_id": 16,
    "url": "http://something.com",
    "title": "Website title",
    "post_created_at": "2015-07-06 02:40:01",
    "post_updated_at": "2015-09-08 22:33:20",
    "tag_map_id": 12,
    "tag_id": 10,
    "tag_name": "cat"
  }
]
```

So there can be multiple results with same post_id but one post can also have multiple tags.

What I want, is to merge these multiple results into one JSON object which contains all the tag-related stuff in array. So there should be only one JSON-object per one post_id. Like the example below:

```
[
  {
    "post_id": 28,
    "site_id": 16,
    "url": "http://something.com",
    "title": "Website title",
    "post_created_at": "2015-07-06 02:40:01",
    "post_updated_at": "2015-09-08 22:33:20",
    "tag_map_id": [11, 12],
    "tag_id": [9, 10],
    "tag_name": ["dog", "cat"]
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this merging in PHP?

Comment: Well to be honest, the problem is that I don't even know where to begin. I have tried to convert the JSON-objects into PHP arrays and do the merging there, but I'm not sure if this is the best way... Also I'm not sure if you could achieve the wanted result already in the query phase and not after??

Comment: Start with these: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). They will convert your JSON strings into arrays, so you can manipulate their elements easier with PHP built-in functions, then cast them as JSON again.
Try it and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `join` at all. I would use Eloquent,

`Post::with('tags')`

and then use `json_encode()` on the resulting Collection.